# CRUD json file with java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to crreate java servlet methods to Create Update or Delete Json file.In json file is information about Dog class.
here is source, still not finished yet 
this is dog class

```
public class Dog {
private String name;
private int age;
private int height;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
```

}

this is  CreateServlet.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.io.FileWriter;

    public class CreateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setAge(20);
        dog.setHeight(15);
        dog.setName("name");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C://tojson.json");
            gson.toJson(dog, writer);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

how to process to Servlet method CRUD json file? thanks

Comment: Where are your `HttpServlet` methods?

Comment: i dont know how to process it with HttpServlet, i created it with java

Comment: First you should to learn how Java Web works.